# Non-negativity of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

On all textbooks that I have read so far, there are only two conditions for which a function $\mu:\Sigma\to[0,+\infty]$ is a measure on a measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$, which are:

1. $\mu(\emptyset)=0$,
2. $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.

However, most of the textbooks leave the non-negativity of $\mu$ as a remark. Why is that not included in the definition? If that follows immediately from the definition, then how?

Comment: You included non-negativity when you wrote $\mu : \Sigma \to \color{red}{[0,+\infty]}$

Answer (score 0):

There are various types of measures: positive measures, real measures, complex measures, vector measure etc. In elementary books dealing with positive measures they impose the condition $\mu(E) \geq 0$ for all sets $E$ in the sigma algebra. Note that if $m$ is Lebesgue measure them $\mu(E)=-m(E)$ defines a set functions satisfying 1) and 2). So positivity does not follow from 1) and 2).

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, because you don't specify exactly what definition you have in mind (the two major typos don't help).

A version of the standard definition is this:

> > **Def** A *measure* on the measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$ is a map $\mu:\Sigma:\to[0,\infty]$ such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.

Non-negativity *is* included in that definition! Saying $\mu:\Sigma\to[0,\infty]$ means precisely that $0\le \mu(E)\le\infty$ for every $e\in\Sigma$.